# Is using css display property to control what different levels of users could access a good idea?

Tags: javascript, css, security

my website requires users to login and I want to allow some users to access more information than others.  I use css display none property to set some of the items on the tab menu to not display depending who the user is. This way, they can't click on the tab to display the info. Is this a good way to restrict access to some materials on the website?  Is there a better way?  I'm using javascript and php.  Thanks.

Comment: So you are saying that potentially the info that some users shouldn't see, is actually on the page but hidden?, or links just hidden, what if they just use a developer toolbar that are available in almost every browser, and see the info, or just manually type the link into the browser url box - bad, bad idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a terrible idea for many reasons, some reasons being:

-Any user like myself will often View Source your page and click around.

-How about people using a browser or setting that doesn't display stylesheets?

-What about users sending or sharing links on Facebook etc..? They can just go to the page right away without logging in or having those permissions?

-Are webcrawlers indexing these pages and putting them in search results?

You need to do this on the back-end and disallow users, not just hide the content.

Comment: I'm using ajax to load pages as users click on a tab and so the url never changes.  I don't think book marking a tab and sending it others will work because the php session variable will ask people to login.  I'm curious to what you could do with view source.  Here is my site: larcheedmonton.org/scheduling_dev  username: test password: me.  You should not be able to see a tab that says "database".  But with a different user, you could.  Thanks.

Comment: "if (log_name_global=="vinh" || log_name_global == "maria") {" is a security concern, but I can see a Volunteers subtab, Employees, To Do, LOA Forms, LOA Summary, Change of Status, all by removing that if statement and refreshing the page, the Database tab shows right up and I have full access to use that tab.

Comment: I have also just pulled and dumped your entire database. If you want a .sql file I can send it to you but here is a screenshot of the data in a web browser: ryankempt.com/Untitled.png

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Ryan.  I did not know that you could edit and then refresh.  I will definitely use php to restrict access.

Comment: That is not good!  Any additional advice on security would be appreciated

Comment: All of your security is client-side, meaning you are allowing ME, the user to have full control of your security measures. For example, your database.js file has verification in it I can just remove, and your PHP files and back-end don't do a single thing to stop me.

Comment: all true.  I really appreciate your comments Ryan.  I need to reprogram my security with php.  Thanks a million.

Comment: Just did that.  I would appreciate it if you removed the screenshot that you posted and delete the sql file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a good idea. You should be restricting what people see using a PHP or other back-end and session variables and/or cookies. Because if you did it the way you explained just now, any person could go into the source of the page and access the hidden content. My personal advice, try not to re-invent the wheel with user registration if you don't need to. Most modern day content management systems will cater for most of your needs.

**Edit:**

Have a look at these content management systems:

- [PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com)
- [Drupal](http://drupal.org)
- [Joomla](http://joomla.org)

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: No, that's not a good idea. 
Why?: Any user understanding browser developer tools can make the information visible if they know its there, or start snooping around.  Once they realize what a mistake the developer made, they would have a hey day looking at everything you attempted to hide...  Plus your sending unnecessary data across the lines that will slow down your page loads, and use up bandwidth, and etc.

Comment: +1 for the additional bandwidth - a concern I didn't think about, but yes!

Answer (score 0):

Hiding this information via CSS is a terrible Idea, The better solution would be to use javascript and the best solution is to use php to this in the backend.

Comment: @LaytonEverson: Yes php is an ideal solutio. but if he doesn't know php js is not bad either.